# Cannot run individual test or test case in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: unit-testing, xcode5, tdd

In Xcode 5, there is usually this checkmark next to the beginning of each test method in the gutter that you can mouse over and click to run that individual case (or the entire test case).  On a particular install of Xcode, I am not able to do this - I can only run the entire test suites by clicking the single play icon in the Test Navigator pane.

Any idea if this can be caused by configuration issue?

[image]

Comment: If you are in the Test Navigator view, your screenshot shows "iOS Tests - 0 tests". No test, no checkmark. I assume you may have solved this since the time of your post, but do you have checked that your test methods all start with the 'test' prefix ?

Comment: Just ran into this myself the other day. Guarantee the tests start with prefix of "test". Mine were all set up and working, then suddenly Xcode stopped recognizing them. I can run the tests from elsewhere and then the tests panel gets populated, but there is no link between the results in the panel and the code. I think I remember being able to select them in there and I would be redirected to their location in the code. This is a very odd bug. I do not know what I did to cause it, and it sucks not having this ability anymore.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have the same error "only when testing on simulator", once I change the scheme to iOS device, I can run the tests!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just running the Testing Scheme and you have Code coverage enabled. The checkmarks/play buttons next to your unit test may not show. I got them to show back up by disabling the code coverage on the scheme. I have multiple targets so I has to create an independent unit testing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 14.2, I found a solution is to close and re-open xcode (:

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have just found that one xib file needed update to a newer version. It sounds weird that this cause the test cases to disappear.

For more details on how to update to a newer version, check the answer of this question: [Xcode 6.1 keeps telling me some PartialInfo.plist couldn't be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693837/xcode-6-1-keeps-telling-me-some-partialinfo-plist-couldnt-be-opened)

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this same problem when switching between XCode 7.0 and XCode 6.4.

If you have two or more versions of Xcode installed make sure that you have the correct simulators installed for running your unit tests. This can be done in two steps:

1. Ensure that `xcode-select` points to the one you're trying to use for your unit tests. Example:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6.4.app/Contents/Developer/`

2. You can reset your simulators like so:

`snapshot reset_simulators`

To install snapshot: https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot