# Xcode 6.1 keeps telling me some PartialInfo.plist couldn't be opened

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

After I upgraded to Xcode 6.1, it kept throwing this exception when I tried to build my existing application. I tried to remove 'MyController' and add back again. But it would throw the same exception with different controller.

```
could not read data from '/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-
dmhwkhbfbxprhycwjeunwtbbtsxj/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/DEV-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyController-
PartialInfo.plist': The file “MyController-PartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no
such file.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer. I have to replace all xib files' IBCocoaTouchPlugin to newer version.

```
<plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6244"/>
```

Comment: this can be done by just selecting the xib and letting xcode open it in interface builder.

Comment: Same with xcode 6.2. We need to select all the xib and let xcode open it in interface builder. Then save all the files.

Comment: Since this *kept* happening to me and just opening the nibs didn't seem to stick, here's a command line one-liner to do it -- remember to commit before you try it and replace the '7520' with whatever version you want to use: `find . -name '*.xib' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/plugIn identifier.*$/plugIn identifier\=\"com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin\" version\=\"7520\"\/\>/g'`

Comment: Awesome fix i'd been having this issue with an old project finally i can run the app on simulator! thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

You can solve it by deleting the content in the DerivedData folder. If you're worried about deleting too many folders, then delete only the folders that start with the name of your current project that you're trying to problem-solve for.
Remember to close XCode before you delete the data

**Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**

Comment: This worked for me. I only had to delete the **Build** folder under my project's DerivedData folder. This allowed me to preserve the **Index** folder which can be rather time- and resource-consuming for Xcode to recreate.

Comment: A safer way to delete Derived Data, is to do it through Xcode --> Window --> Projects: Select your project (on the left pane) and click on the "Delete" button next to Derived Data in the right pane.

Answer (score 3):

For me (with Xcode 6.3) this was happening with a file that happened to end in ~iPhone.xib. I changed it end in the all lower-case ~iphone.xib, and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally happens when you open old version xibs 
nothing to do only click on the xib in file panel its version will automatically changed/updated with newer version.

so also you not need to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I moved my .plist file to a new folder. You have to go into the Targets list (select the top bar on the left vertical menu of Xcode, the one that has the name of your project, and then select Targets on the vertical menu second from the left) and find the Identity section. From there, select the button that lets you specify the new path of the .plist file.

If that doesn't work, then try deleting your project's folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and building again.

Answer (score 0):

Several of you have come up with the partial answer.

I believe this issue is related to Apple's "fix" for when XIBs were loading slowly when they referenced custom fonts. They now store the custom font info in a xibnamePartialInfo.plist file in your derivedData folder.

Now if your app contains xibname~iPhone.xib AND xibname.xib, only the PartialInfo.plist file for xibname~iPhone.xib gets created and you see the error. Opening the xib in InterfaceBuilder had the side-effect of creating this file which is why the problem appeared to go away (until the next clean).

So the solution is to rename all ~iPhone files to something else (dash works as a replacement for tilde). Apparently its the tilde that is hindering the creation of the PartialInfo.plist file for the root XIB

Answer (score 0):

Common answer for most of question... Restart Xcode. It works for me.