# StoryBoard Compile Time Error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

We are getting the compile time error in xcode while compiling the story Board in Xcode 6.2.

> CompileStoryboard GamePlan/Resources/en.lproj/FindAMatch.storyboard
>       cd /Users/nitishverma/Desktop/SF/GamePLan/gameplan-ios
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --errors --warnings --notices --module GamePlan --minimum-deployment-target 8.1 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/nitishverma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GamePlan-fiaexwrckwvuidceojvkqvxdzfvw/Build/Intermediates/GamePlan.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GamePlan.build/FindAMatch-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/nitishverma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GamePlan-fiaexwrckwvuidceojvkqvxdzfvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GamePlan.app/en.lproj /Users/nitishverma/Desktop/SF/GamePLan/gameplan-ios/GamePlan/Resources/en.lproj/FindAMatch.storyboard
>
> //Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
>
> (null): could not read data from '/Users/nitishverma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GamePlan-fiaexwrckwvuidceojvkqvxdzfvw/Build/Intermediates/GamePlan.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GamePlan.build/FindAMatch-SBPartialInfo.plist': The file “FindAMatch-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

We also tried cleaning the derived data and restarting the Xcode. Doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693837/xcode-6-1-keeps-telling-me-some-partialinfo-plist-couldnt-be-opened